# Join an IRC channel read-only

Tags: irc, irssi

Is it possible to `/join #channel` in IRC in such a way that I can read but not write to the channel?  My motivation is to be able to keep an eye on some channels without the risk of fat-fingering some nonsense in there.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean within irssi? There is `botti`, which should let you read a channel without being interactive to the channel. From there, you could just `tail -f` the log*. From `man -k`:

```
botti (1)            - Run an irssi module, such as a bot, without a UI
```

Alternatively, if you're a chanop you can join the channel and then set usermode +b for that user and they won't be able to send to the channel. Some networks will allow you to set a channel mode such that only registered users can speak, or channel mode +m so that only voiced users can speak, but it varies a lot.

If you gave more information I could give you a more specific answer.

**note: you can create a new window in irssi with no channel joined to it, and have that window run `/exec -o tail ~/irclogs/network/#channelname.log`, and it will output everything from that channel via the log you're saving, and be un-interactive.*